# Mid 2000s cartoon about a pair of mischievous twins wearing striped pyjamas

Tags: story-identification, tv

I think it used to be aired in CN (Cartoon Network), it was a series about a pair of twins wearing a striped pyjamas. I think they lived in a groomy mansion or an old big house. I believe they had a sister but I could be wrong about that. A popular girl was the antagonist as she seemed to despise the twins. I believe they were kind of genius as they invented gadgets.

The twins looked somewhat like salad fingers, they weren't actually evil, just mischievous.

Comment: Was anything about this science fictional or fantastical? The gadgets bit seems like it might be but you probably want to flesh it out some more.

Comment: That said twins in striped pyjamas... [Bananas in Pyjamas](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0286342/)?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Nope, they were humans, they looked gloomy kinda like a mixture of Salad Fingers and Wednesday from Adam's Family Values. Without mentioning that Bananas in Pyjamas stripes are vertical, the ones I'm talking were horizontal

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot As an Aussie, I'm ashamed you beat me to that! :-D

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Could this be "Edgar and Ellen"?

Seen below are twins (Not identical!) wearing striped clothing, holding some gadget looking devices.

Here's a summary from IMDB:

> Based on a book series by Charles Ogden, lively animated series EDGAR
> & ELLEN revolves around the titular 12-year-old twins, whose primary
> mission in life is playing mischievous practical jokes (on each other
> as well as classmates and teachers) and putting the snooty residents
> of Nod's Limbs in their place. (Edgar and Ellen's adventures air as
> both an episodic cartoon series and longer specials.) Edgar and Ellen
> are voiced by Kathleen Barr and Jillian Michaels, respectively.

[image]